# ildasm on Linux via nuget installation: ildasm executable not found

Tags: .net, linux, nuget, nuget-package, ildasm

I installed ildasm on my Ubuntu 18.04 via

```
nuget install Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm
```

I somehow ended up with two directories:

```
/home/vagrant/.nuget/packages/microsoft.netcore.ildasm/2.0.8/
/home/vagrant/Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm.2.0.8/
```

but none of them contained any dll or exe:

```
vagrant@ubuntu1804:~/Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm.2.0.8$ ls
LICENSE.TXT  Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm.2.0.8.nupkg
Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm.nuspec  _rels  runtime.json  THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES.TXT  
version.txt
```

Where did nuget put the main application, i.e. the equivalent to the ildasm.exe on Windows?

Or am I doing something wrong to install ildasm on Linux?

Comment: You should use the global tool version, https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ildasm/

Comment: @LexLi I am not sure if this version is really the same as the "original" Microsoft ildasm.exe. The global tools version says "dotnet ildasm 0.12.2.0" and the other one is version 2.0.8.

Comment: The NuGet package you used was never documented to be the right thing to use. For years, Microsoft didn't really have a tool for cross platform, https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6223 So that third party global tool can be the best option at this moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider two ways to install *ildasm*.

**Using nuget-package**

- define [RID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) (Runtime Identifier)

```sh
dotnet --info

# execution result
..
Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64 # <----
..
```

- download the package *runtime.{RID}.Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm*. For my case it is: [runtime.ubuntu.18.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.ubuntu.18.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILDAsm/)
- unarchive it and extract executable file *'/runtimes/{RID}/native/ildasm'*
- grant it execution permission and copy to .NET runtime folder (call *dotnet --list-runtimes* to list runtimes)

```sh
chmod +x ildasm
sudo mv ildasm /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/{version}/
```

- create symlink

```sh
ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/{version}/ildasm ildasm
```

- run ildasm

```sh
./ildasm {path}/project.dll >> {path}/project.il
```

The same steps are applicable for [ilasm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.ubuntu.18.04-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.ILAsm/).

**Using [dotnet-ildasm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ildasm/) tool**

```sh
# install .net core runtime if required
# sudo apt-get update; \
#   sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
#   sudo apt-get update && \
#   sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-runtime-3.0

# find required tool
dotnet tool search ildasm
# output:
# Package ID         Latest Version      Authors      Downloads      Verified
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# dotnet-ildasm      0.12.2              pjbgf        100154                 
# dotasm             1.0.1               DotAsm       434 

# install tool
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ildasm
```

Output IL to file:

```sh
# go to project folder
cd ../project/bin/Debug/netx.x

dotnet ildasm program.dll -o program.il
```

Comment: `dotnet-ildasm` is a completely different implementation of a .NET disassembler, and does not share code with the Microsoft tool `ildasm`.

Comment: This package has been deprecated as part of the .NET Package Deprecation effort. Does this mean that its use may not work as intended? (https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/217)